# Есть выпадающий список, нужно отсортировать элементы по алфавиту

Tags: c#

Windows Forms
Как проще всего это сделать? Без ручной реализации

Comment: Используйте  linq

Answer (score 1):

Если это обычный текст, нет связи с источником данных, то можете использовать свойство ComboBox.Sorted или отсортировать данные предварительно до добавления в ComboBox:

```
string[] dataArray = new string[] { "Денис", "Антон", "Владимир", "Борис", "Григорий" }; 

comboBox1.Items.AddRange(dataArray);
// вариант первый - включить свойсво кортировки
comboBox1.Sorted = true;

// вариант второй - отсортировать элементы до добавления в список
var sortedArray = dataArray.OrderBy(o => o).ToArray();
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(sortedArray);
```